# Laravel route for form not working

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am trying to upload files to the server, but after i submit the form i always get a Controller method not found error i dont know where am i going wrong.
Or if any good tutorial for this purpose?

this is my form

```
{{ Form::open(array('files' => true , 'action' => array('ProfileController@multiUpload'  ))) }}
{{ Form::file('file[]', array('multiple'=>true))}}
{{ Form::hidden('folder', $data->username) }}
{{ Form::submit('Upload To Gallery') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

this is my route

```
Route::post('multiupload', 'ProfileController@multiUpload');
```

and this is my controller method

```
class ProfileController extends BaseController
{
    public function multiUpload()
    {
        if (Input::hasFile('file[]')) 
        {
            $all_uploads = Input::file('file[]');
            $folder = Input::get('folder');

            // Make sure it really is an array
            if (!is_array($all_uploads))
            {
                $all_uploads = array($all_uploads);
            }

            $error_messages = array();

            // Loop through all uploaded files
            foreach ($all_uploads as $upload)
            {
                // Ignore array member if it's not an UploadedFile object, just to be extra safe
                if (!is_a($upload, 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile'))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                $validator = Validator::make(
                    array('file' => $upload),
                    array('file' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png|image|max:5000')
                );

                if ($validator->passes()) 
                {
                    Image::upload($upload, 'uploads/'.$folder , true);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    // Collect error messages
                    $error_messages[] = 'File "' . $upload->getClientOriginalName() . '":' .    $validator->messages()->first('file');
                }
            }

            // Redirect, return JSON, whatever...
            return $error_messages;
        } 
        else 
        {
            // No files have been uploaded
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error????

Comment: Controller Method Not found Exception

Comment: restful controller????

Comment: updated the code above, can u suggest any tutorial for this

Comment: Can you see the source of the form ?

Comment: yes i can see the form this is how it looks


<form method="POST" action="http://www.hapwork.com/multiupload" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="V0zMnMNXOzWcnLG2YpaXjlVdE1FT9BjymQYUviHq"><input multiple="1" name="file[]" type="file"><input name="folder" type="hidden" value="monil"><input type="submit" value="Upload To Gallery"></form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method should be lowercase change `multiUpload()` to `multiupload()` and try again.

Comment: But he didn't use restful controllers

Comment: @ahmedhamdy that's true.

Comment: how do i change this to add RESTfull controller and get it working?

Comment: i updated my controller to restfull controller to get that working, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error is cause by the misspelling of BaseContoller

Change

```
class ProfileController extends Basecontroller
```

To

```
class ProfileController extends BaseController
```